# pdo variable is undefined in mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, visibility

I have an index.php which is like:

```
require_once("../resources/config.php");
require_once(LIBRARY_PATH . "/mysql.php");
...
if(checkIfMailExists($email)) {
    $error = true;
    $errormsg = "This e-mail is already in use!";
}
```

mysql.php is:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['db1']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['db1']['dbname'], $config['db']['db1']['username'], $config['db']['db1']['password']);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Cant connect to mysql DB!";
}

function checkIfMailExists($email)  {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $num = $pdo->query($query);
    if($num->rowCount() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it appears, that $pdo from function is undefined. Even if i remove try-catch.
The only way i fixed it - i sent $pdo as a parameter to function, but it seems to be wrong. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: [Scope scope scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a PDO connection as a parameter is actually the only sane way to do this. It is indeed good to know that you could use the `global` keyword, but the optimal way to write code that is possible to maintain is explicitely stating dependencies, and [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) them

```
function mailExists (PDO $pdo, $email)  {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->rowCount() > 0;
}
if (mailExists($pdo, $email) {}
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) about PDO and prepared statements. Notice how I took advantage of named parameters to ensure that no sql injection is possible from this code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to create local variables within a function without needing to do anything to declare them. Just start using a variable, and it's assumed to be a local variable.

This means if you *want* to access a global variable inside a function, you must declare it explicitly:

```
function checkIfMailExists($email)  {
    global $pdo;
    . . .
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use global, but pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Qirel, yes, I agree with that. I just wanted to answer the OP's question. It's worthwhile to understand how variable scope works in PHP.